# Firebase Blaze plan and Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Unfortunately Firebase's Flame plan disappeared and I now have to deal with Blaze plan, which I'm not fan of because of it's "unlimited" budget (but my wallet isn't). Yesterday I was coding and by mistake made a loop that called 3 Cloud Functions, I spotted the loop fast enough to stop the carnage.

In only 15 seconds of execution, I've been able to trigger more than 10K requests, and without errors, that a pretty good performance of Firebase, but it's scary as well! How can I cap this to throttle requests coming from users? I'm pretty confident in my code, but as we all know if someone gets my Firebase config file, I'm done.

I'm a solo developer and it's my first app done on my spare time, I don't want to to become a mess because of triggering reads / writes / Cloud Functions. No one is perfect, everyone makes mistakes, maybe I didn't spot a small bug in my code that'll reveal it's true potential only once in production. I'm not asking Firebase to handle my mistakes, but I'd like to be able to stop the CF and Firebase if I want to.

My only desire is to sleep confident, I don't want to wake up one morning with a 10.000$ bill. I've read that's it's possible to totally disable billing account on a project with CloudFunctions, but what will happen to my Firebase Storage bucket for example (for the storage superior to the Spark plan)? And it doesn't seem easy to do.

Firebase is a great product and I love how easy / fun it is to use, but now that budget locked plans as Flame are gone I feel really trapped now that my application is almost ready to go into production, and I don't think I'm the only one out there.

Comment: Hi, maybe you can use a budget in GCP, Firebase as a part of Google Products is based on GCP ( Google Cloud Platform ) Technologies, all your Infrastructure is managed by a project and a google account. As being part of this environment, you can take advantage of the GCP capabilities; on my recommendation, you can set a Budget, for example, that limits cuotas of the capacity of any at the google products including cloud functions or setting alerts for the advice of any weird behavior. I let you the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but I've already set alerts to a certain percentage under what I expect it to be at the maximum. Unfortunately, this setting is just an alert, if you're sleeping with your phone away, you can have a really big surprise on the next morning.

When I see what I've been capable of in 15 seconds, I let you imagine in several hours :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah you've stumbled onto the 'rate-limiting' conundrum. Not to worry, I've spent many nights worrying about this myself.

In order to get a bit more control over your application, you're going to have to link your project to [google cloud platform](https://cloud.google.com/). Then navigate to `IAM & Admin>Quotas` (once you've selected your firebase project).

Now you might be overwhelmed initially, and confused as to why there are so many Cloud functions API limiters. These quotas should allow you to rate limit your cloud functions API (similar to what twitter does) in a number of ways, including but not limited to:

- Read Requests per day
- Read requests per 100 seconds
- Function invocations per 100 seconds
- Function invocations per day
- etc

The API that will be listed are the ones you've enabled, so you can set limits for cloud storage as well.

By default, the max number of invocations per second is set to the maximum of 5000 invocations per day on the spark plan. but according to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/quotas), the absolute maximum is 100,000,000/100 seconds!

Also worth having a look at is the [pricing docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing), which have a nice example of a typical monthly use case for a successful app. To grossly oversimplify, a single invocation costs $0.0000004, hence 10,000,000 invocations will cost you a whopping $3.20. However don't let that very low cost fool you, if you write some terrible code and it has exponential complexity (like reading every document in a firestore collection every invocation), you could get slapped with an exponential cost. So make sure you set those quotas :)

Remember, server admin is as much a part of the application as the code itself. If your app goes to production, be prepared to spend some time each day going through the Google cloud dashboard and checking limits, analyzing trends, etc. This way you can kind of step up the amount of invocations you can allow per day and sleep well knowing that if you shoot yourself in the foot, you won't bleed too much.

Best of luck with it

Despicable B.

Comment: Hi, thank you for a such detailled answer :) I'll try what you said. Yesterday when I created the loop I was on Blaze plan and yeah, it's insane how much it can handle requests without a problem! 

Yes, at first pricing does not seems much at all, but like you said, I'm not worried about normal usage, I'm worried about bugs / hackers. I estimate my daily reads usage per user of approximately 500 Firestore reads / 50 writes, which I don't think is that much. 

Yes, I'm used to manage servers, but clearly, Firebase goal is to allow you some spare time on your actual app code, not servers

Comment: No worries, Firebase is serverless however you'll still need to change the quota as time goes on (like if you start with 10 users you can use your estimate of 500 reads each which gives you 5000 for your daily quota. I'm not aware of any automatic quota setting methods, but it'd be worth having a look for (I do it with Google Cloud Run).

Comment: It's fine, if I'm doing logs with my CF so I know if everything went as it should. I'm not against having to changes the quota over time if it allows me to sleep well. Even If I have to check twice a day if everything is okay, I'll, it's not a big deal, but when I saw what I could do yesterday in 15 seconds, I really freaked out. This app is done on my spare time and is meant to be a fun thing, not a nightmare. Did you saw quota working after you changed the settings on your dashboard? I mean, did you ever hit a limit?

Comment: Yeah I've hit the limit in the past, because we all mess up, but you'll be fine so long as your limits are set. However some advice on whether your app is likely to hit the limit, it depends on what your code does. Firebase is built mainly for web and mobile applications. Like if you wanted to make your own Facebook or YouTube, or make a turn based strategy game then firebase is great and you can do some basic modelling to accurately predict what your demand will be. Firebase isn't great for dedicated multiplayer games though for various reasons, for that I'd recommend Agones.

Comment: May I ask what limit do you advise to set? I use Firestore + Cloud Functions and other stuff of Firebase, but only those two are concerned by the blaze plan. My app is a mobile app (Flutter) + web (VueJS). Actually it's a small "social" network, where every user have his profile, so I guess for this kind of application Firebase is a great tool. Actually my app is working as a charm, even had friends testing it without any problem, but well, it's not in production. Thanks for the Agones, never heard of it before, who knows, maybe I'll need it one day :)

Comment: I'd start off with setting it to the same values as the free tier (so you can develop your app without worrying about being charged $2000 for a screw up). After you're confident it all works, set yourself a target (say 500 users), get an estimate of how many reads and writes each user will require (you can do this through testing your app and checking the analytics for it). Then do the math and set your limits. Unless your app supports multiple languages and is available in other countries, you can rely on demand falling at night, so during those times you can make changes.

Comment: Hi, I've set low values that I know will fail even during testing phase, at least I can catch errors (based on the doc when quota is exceeded it returns an error 500 but I want to see it). Yes my app is multilanguage but at first I'll target only western europe so I'm fine. Big thanks again for your help, discorvering this Quota section is a relief, too bad Firestore isn't a thing we can't manage for now.

Comment: Hi, did you received the last Google's team email? They're removing most of the limiters to "simplifying its quota approval system". Seems like it's based on users feedback. I really don't understand, the more possibilites you have, the better it is, even if it's a little bit longer to configure.

Comment: Haven't had a look at that, I've been busy writing up training documentation. The changes will probably pertain to a restructuring of how the quotas are set (like rather than have to go in and out of different menus for ingress and egress for the same service, you'll be able to configure it in a file or a simplified menu). However I don't know the specifics, but I'm happy to discuss it with you when they release the changes. I don't think they're going to just up and remove support, as that would ruin the applications that have existing implementations relying on IAM.