# Firebase Callable CloudFunction and protection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'd like to protect my Firebase Callable Cloud Functions against spam abuse (massive calls to them). From what I've read there and there, there is no built in solution to do so. Recently, Cloud Armor appeared, I'll check on it.

My question is, how can I use Callable Cloud Functions behind a protection (no matter what it is, CloudFlare, Cloud Armor...). Callable are meant to be called directly from SDK, I can't provide a direct URL to them. Do I have to "convert" them to standard HTTP calls and do the job by myself if I want them to be protected? There must be a solution, people from Firebase didn't built a such fun tool to use to let it be spammed with no solutions.

I know that I can use quotas, I'm not talking about scalability. Even if I put quotas, the only result I'll get is a non working app as real users will be put into queue.

Thank you

Comment: Answering myself: the only way I found is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58178243/is-there-a-way-to-restrict-public-access-from-firebase-callable-could-functions but then we loose all the advantages of callable functions and we've to write an standard HTTP call.

Comment: If you have an answer for your own question, don't leave that in a comment - you can use a proper answer and accept it as correct.  But I suggest that you explain the answer instead of just linking to another question.

Comment: It's not really an answer, that's why I've put "The only way I found". For me, this is just a workaround, this is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

Upon further investigation, it seems that Quotas in the IAM settings only account for calls to the Cloud Functions API, which regulates the creation, deletion and listing functions to the developer.

I did a little more reading and found [this](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/rate-limiting-strategies-techniques#cloud_functions). The document outlines google's recommended approach to defending against attacks, notably the [max-instancing](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/max-instances) option

```
gcloud functions deploy FUNCTION_NAME --max-instances 10 FLAGS...
```

This would constrain the maximum number of concurrent instances that can be invoked, thus resulting in a form of [rate-limiting](https://stripe.com/blog/rate-limiters).

However this isn't exactly what you want. You want full control of rate limiting your application in a scalable and configurable manner.

For that, Google recommends using **Redis**, and a full tutorial on how to get Redis working with cloud functions and memory-store is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cloud-functions-rate-limiting).

I haven't used Redis myself, but from reading the tutorial, it sounds exactly like what you need.

Sorry for not reading the documentation so closely, hopefully this helps solve your issue.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

The protection mechanisms for Google Cloud Functions aren't really obvious, but it goes a little like this:

I'll be quoting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47948561/are-google-cloud-functions-protected-from-ddos-attacks) post's answer

> Cloud functions sits behind the Google Front End which mitigates and absorbs many Layer 4 and below attacks, such as SYN floods, IP fragment floods, port exhaustion, etc.

Those who've been to a university or studied general purpose computing will recognize layers as the different parts of a communication model (e.g. Layer 1 is the physical layer, Layer 2 is the data link, etc).

You can read a bit about it [here](https://www.webopedia.com/reference/osi-layers/).

So bottom line, you're protected from most attacks by default. But its a good idea to implement rate limits and quotas just in case.

The other kind of attack you might be concerned about is a trickle attack, where lots of computers ping your backend over and over slowly.

Let's say the attacker has 1000 computers at his disposal and pings your backend once a second (assuming your function does not call any other functions).

Now assuming Google's security doesn't catch it, cloud functions cost is $0.0000004/invocation, so 10 million invocations will cost you $4.

in order to hit 10 million invocations, it will take 10000 seconds (~167 minutes or about 2.7 hours).

This is very unlikely to happen, as $4/2.7 = $1.48/hr that he's wasting you. Trust me, there's far more profitable exploits out there ;)

You should be fine when starting up, but if you get to the stage where you're a big website and are concerned about attacks moreso than you are now, then definitely cloud armor is a good choice.

Cloud armor allows you to filter traffic based on IP, Geolocation and other custom match parameters that you specify on the L3-L7 levels. But depending on your application, it might be a bit overkill.

You can read a bit more about it [here](https://cloud.withgoogle.com/next/sf/sessions?session=SEC205#security).

Best of luck

- Despicable B.

Comment: Hi, I was sure I had already seen your nickname, you answered me there for another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62833346/firebase-blaze-plan-and-cloud-functions :) Thanks again for this really detailed answer. Unfortunately, most of the quotas for CF have been deprecated, the "only" way now is to limit the functions instances if I'm right.

Comment: Yeah all the region specific quotas have been deprecated, but if you scroll down below all the flak, you can still set read requests per minute, write requests per minute, read requests per 100 seconds per user, etc. All of these are now GLOBAL settings. 

You can find all these options under IAM & Admin > Quotas > Cloud Functions API.

I can't find a filter that removes all the deprecated options, so it's easy to see how one can get lost :P

If you want more control over quotas, I'd recommend using cloud run with ESPv2, although it has a pretty steep learning curve. Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help. Are you sure about those quotas? ("read requests per 100 seconds per user" / "writerequests per 100 seconds per user"), from what I've read in the documentation, it's used for the CLI (deploying functions) and not the end users, unless I'm wrong? The only "real" way to limit CloudFunctions now that most of quotas have been deprecated is the "max instance" parameter.

Comment: You are indeed correct, let me update my answer